# Program installation failed

Tags: applications, appcenter, thirdpartyapps

I need help, I use Elementary OS 0.4.1 *Loki*. I need to install a certain program, but there's an annoying error that gives me every time i try to install ANYTHING- from the terminal,the app store,from .deb files

[image: it gives me this error]

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Please add enough details so people can attempt to reproduce the issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 0.4.1 Loki.  You are installing from the terminal, so did you do:

```
sudo apt update
```

then:

```
sudo apt install <name-of-package>
```

You could also do a search to confirm the existence of `libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0` as:

```
sudo apt-cache search libgstreamer-plugins
```

When I do the above my system confirms that `libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0` is in the repository.

If the above fails, maybe try a general upgrade to reset the system first, as:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Then try to install your package again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Eddy (via AppCentre). Eddy is a program to help you install .deb packages through a graphical user interface.